# How does one use GHC in agda with VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, agda, agda-mode

I get the error:

```
No backend called 'GHC' (installed backends: GHCNoMain, QuickLaTeX)
```

which is very strange because my vscode says that's what it's using:

[image]

what is going on?

cross posted: https://github.com/banacorn/agda-mode-vscode/issues/99